# Code smells stopped showing up in Sonar

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

So, first off, I want to make it clear that I don't believe that Sonar is failing here, it's almost entirely something I did.

I recently went through and upgraded our Sonar install from 5.x to 6.1.  I then upgraded to the latest sonar-scanner and ran an analysis, and it looked great.  All the smells and bugs showed up.

Then, I went through and added code coverage reports, and as soon as I did that, the smells/bugs went to zero...even though the code wasn't changed.

I added:

```
-Dsonar.cs.dotcover.reportsPaths=tests/**/test/coverage.html
-Dsonar.cs.xunit.reportsPaths=tests/**/test/xunit.xml
```

And all of the coverage and unit test information shows up now, but the smells and bugs have disappeared.

Have I somehow overridden the static analysis portion by supplying these reports?  Is there something I need to do to bring them back?

Answer (score 0):

The answer:

During the upgrade it appears all of the rules became disabled.

Answer (score 0):

when we upgrade sonarqube, Quality profiles doesn't have any rules. We can restore these profile again by using the following steps:

1. login as administration
2. go to quality profile
3. click on down arrow button narrow to create button
4. We will get 2 options 
   a. Restore profile b. Restore build-in profile
5. if we previously took the backup then click on Restore Profile, Otherwise Click on Restore build-in profile
6. choose language and restore it again
7. run the sonar-runner again